# android compare 2 images and highlight difference

Tags: java, android, opencv

2 Images will be provided. We need to find differences between them and highlight them.

So far I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022578/highlight-differences-between-images) in JAVA but as BufferedImage is not supported in android, I am unable to proceed further. I have come close to comparing pixels of 2 Bitmaps but facing issue ahead.

I have also tried comparing pixels of two bitmap, but it highlights all the non-white colors

```
void findDifference(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
{
    if (firstImage.getHeight() != secondImage.getHeight() && firstImage.getWidth() != secondImage.getWidth())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Images size are not same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    boolean isSame = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstImage.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstImage.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            if (firstImage.getPixel(i,j) == secondImage.getPixel(i,j))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                differentPixels.add(new Pixel(i,j));
                secondImage.setPixel(i,j, Color.YELLOW); //for now just changing difference to yello color
                isSame = false;
            }
        }
    }
    imgOutput.setImageBitmap(secondImage);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing? Do you have any code you can provide to help us see what you've already tried? any stacktraces or error logs?

Comment: I have added details of code and what result I am having. Thanks

Comment: Just a comment but your test to verify that your images have the same size is wrong. IT should be `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @Sunreef can you post images as well? May be they ARE different? Usually you need to allow some eps difference like `(Color.red(firstImage.getPixel(i,j)) - Color.red(secondImage.getPixel(i,j))) < eps && (Color.blue(firstImage.getPixel(i,j)) - Color.blue(secondImage.getPixel(i,j))) < eps && (Color.green(firstImage.getPixel(i,j)) - Color.green(secondImage.getPixel(i,j))) < eps`, try eps=3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of digital color meter I detected there is very slight difference between colors of visually looking similar images quite similar what @taarraas also suggested. so I took a threshold value and solved it like this.

```
private static final int threashold = 10;

void findDifference(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
{
    if (firstImage.getHeight() != secondImage.getHeight() || firstImage.getWidth() != secondImage.getWidth())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Images size are not same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    boolean isSame = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstImage.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstImage.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            int pixel = firstImage.getPixel(i,j);
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

            int pixel2 = secondImage.getPixel(i,j);
            int redValue2 = Color.red(pixel2);
            int blueValue2 = Color.blue(pixel2);
            int greenValue2 = Color.green(pixel2);

            if (Math.abs(redValue2 - redValue) + Math.abs(blueValue2 - blueValue) + Math.abs(greenValue2 - greenValue) <= threashold)
//                if (firstImage.getPixel(i,j) == secondImage.getPixel(i,j))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                differentPixels.add(new Pixel(i,j));
                secondImage.setPixel(i,j, Color.YELLOW); //for now just changing difference to yello color
                isSame = false;
            }
        }
    }
    imgOutput.setImageBitmap(secondImage);
}
```

Comment: For best performance use getPixels(), not getPixel() and match each key in array with while(). ~2 Seconds of difference on process an hd image, in realtime process of a video need more speed.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the images pixel by pixel you can do it like this:

```
private void findDifference(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage) {
    Bitmap bmp = secondImage.copy(secondImage.getConfig(), true);

    if (firstImage.getWidth() != secondImage.getWidth()
            || firstImage.getHeight() != secondImage.getHeight()) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < firstImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstImage.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (firstImage.getPixel(i, j) != secondImage.getPixel(i, j)) {
                bmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
    }

    imgOutput.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: I see some refactoring, but no changes in logic. Did I miss something?

Comment: @taarraas You are right. I hadn't tested Haris's code, but I have just tested it and it's working fine