# Android find difference between two ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am developing a puzzle game like find differences on images in Android (Java).
So how can i know, where user touched on image, and is it right place where user touched.

Comment: check this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977839/android-compare-2-images-and-highlight-difference

Answer (score 0):

make some `CustomView extends View` and override [`onTouchEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method. or handle all touch events in `Activity` by overriding [`dispatchTouchEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). you can obtain precise point of touch/action with `getX()` and `getY()` methods of `MotionEvent` (which is an object passed to both methods mentioned above), now its your turn to do some math and calculate which item has been touched (by default `Activity` is dispatching touch events to its layout e.g. inflated from XML)